# GDB cannot step over a function if the following lines don't include a decision or branch

Tags: c++, gdb, powerpc, gdbserver

I am having problems with debugging (stepping over) in C++ with GDB.
I have an in house developed [RTOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) which runs on a PowerPC [e500mc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC_e500) target.

Software versions: GCC 4.9.2, gdb-server 5 ~(I am not sure about the exact version), GDB 7.9.1 (I also tried 8.3.1).

The source file is compiled with the `-g` and `-O0` parameters.

The problem seems to be occurring in C++ after stepping over a function if the following lines don't include any jump, branch instruction for a certain amount, GDB lost track where to stop at function return and continue running.

I've tried the same code on an x86-64 target version. It runs as expected without any issue. The first, I checked was gdb-server's target porting part, and then logged the messaging between the host and the target. As you can see below, the problem seems to be at the GDB side since GDB itself decides where to put a breakpoint.

There is example code exploiting the error, and I also added the log file. The lines starting with "gdb:" are the messages from GDB to the target. I don't include the gdb-server's responses to avoid confusion.

Other lines are printed by the target. <..> are the comments added by me later. It tells the meaning of the code, data or address, and also what I did at that time. I also include the ELF file's related part to make it more understandable.

Here it what happens. At first I load my program to the target, with auto start disabled. The program is in memory and waiting for my command to run. Then I attach to the process for debugging. GDB takes over and starts communication. After some handshaking and queries, it catches the process. It wasn't running, so it catch at the very beginning, initialization code before the main function at 0x210106E8. So GDB knows that I want to stop at my code (*main*), puts a breakpoint at *main*'s first instruction after the function's stack operations at 0x21010250.

Then programs runs on the target and catch a trap exception at a breakpoint. When the execution stops GDB removes the breakpoint (trap instruction) and puts back the original instruction.

Later I do a step over which is line int i=0. GDB sets on the trace mode and starts the execution.

The program catches the trace exception after running the first instruction. Since I am not in instruction stepping mode, GDB starts execution again until the c line ends, GDB catches the second trace exception and reaches the end of the c line sets of the trace mode.

Now we are at the function call line and stepping over again. GDB sets on the trace mode and start executing the program. The program calls the function and catches the trace exception. GDB sees it's not in the function (main) we are interested in since we are stepping over, and sets a breakpoint for function return point. The program starts executing and prints the message. The function returns and hits the breakpoint at 0x2101025C. So far so good.

It should have stopped here, since my initial command, which is stepping over function call, is completed, but continues.

Now as you can see on the log output, GDB starts queries about the code block, which it has done before, but not with a much greater number, looking for 52 instructions ahead (which are all the `i++`s). GDB removes the breakpoint and sets the trace mode on and executes the first instruction of the *i++* command.

After the first instruction executed and the exception caught, again the 52 instruction queries. After all this, GDB should set on the trace mode and start executing. Instead of this, it puts a breakpoint before the current PC, at the address of the instruction it just executed. When trace mode is off and when the execution starts, the program executes to completion since the breakpoint will not be hit.

If I reduce the number of i++'s to the point, where in 52 instruction query GDB will see some jump or branch, everything works as expected.

And if the same code compiled as C, not C++, again everything works as expected.

As I mentioned earlier, same code running on a x86 target, everything works as expected.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printHello(void)
{
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    printHello();
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    return 0;
}
```

Terminal output:

```
<attach to process>
gdb:qSupported:multiprocess+;qRelocInsn+
gdb:!
gdb:Hgp0.0
gdb:QNonStop:0
gdb:qTStatus
gdb:?
gdb:qXfer:osdata:read:processes:0,35b
gdb:qXfer:threads:read::0,35b
gdb:vAttach;10000
stopping 65537 @210106e8 <_posix_lib_process_start>
gdb:qC
gdb:Hgp10000.10001
gdb:g
gdb:qSymbol::
gdb:m21010250,4 <main>
gdb:m21010250,4
gdb:m21010250,4
gdb:m210151c8,4 <_ZSt9terminatev>
gdb:m2102e288,4 <_Unwind_DebugHook>
gdb:qXfer:threads:read::0,763
gdb:qXfer:osdata:read:processes:0,763
gdb:qXfer:threads:read::0,763
gdb:Z0,21010250,4
gdb:m21010250,4 <backup>
gdb:X21010250,0:
gdb:X21010250,4:}] <put breakpoint @ main>
gdb:vCont?
gdb:vCont;c:p10000.-1 <cont all, breakpoint ready>
starting 65537 @210106e8
trap callback
stopping 65537 @21010250 <stop @ breakpoint>
gdb:m21010250,4
gdb:m21010254,4
gdb:m21010258,4
gdb:m2101023c,4 <main's head>
gdb:m2101023c,4
gdb:m21010240,4
gdb:m21010244,4
gdb:m21010248,4
gdb:m2101024c,4
gdb:m21441fa0,4
gdb:g
gdb:qXfer:threads:read::0,763
gdb:X21010250,4:9 <remove breakpoint>
gdb:qXfer:threads:read::0,763
gdb:qXfer:threads:read::0,763
gdb:qXfer:threads:read::0,763
<stop @ int=0 line>

<step>
gdb:m2102e288,4 <backup>
gdb:X2102e288,4:}] <??put breakpoint>
gdb:m21010250,4
gdb:vCont;s:p10000.10001;c:p10000.-1 <stop thread, set trace>
single step set
starting 65537 @21010250
trace callback <instruction complete exception>
stopping 65537 @21010254
single step reset
gdb:m21010254,4
gdb:m21010258,4
gdb:m2101023c,4
gdb:m2101023c,4
gdb:m21010240,4
gdb:m21010244,4
gdb:m21010248,4
gdb:m2101024c,4
gdb:m21010250,4
gdb:m21441fa0,4
gdb:g
gdb:m21010254,4
gdb:vCont;s:p10000.10001;c:p10000.-1 <stop thread, set trace>
single step set
starting 65537 @21010254
trace callback <instruction complete exception>
stopping 65537 @21010258
single step reset <step done, new c line>
gdb:m21010258,4
gdb:m2101023c,4
gdb:m2101023c,4
gdb:m21010240,4
gdb:m21010244,4
gdb:m21010248,4
gdb:m2101024c,4
gdb:m21010250,4
gdb:m21441fa0,4
gdb:g
gdb:qXfer:threads:read::0,763
gdb:X2102e288,4:N <??remove breakpoint>
gdb:qXfer:threads:read::0,763
gdb:qXfer:threads:read::0,763
<stop @ printHello() line>

<step>
gdb:m2102e288,4
gdb:X2102e288,4:}] <??put breakpoint>
gdb:m21010258,4
gdb:vCont;s:p10000.10001;c:p10000.-1 <stop thread, set trace>
single step set
starting 65537 @21010258
trace callback
stopping 65537 @210101e8 <printHello>
single step reset
gdb:m210101e8,4
gdb:m210101ec,4
gdb:m210101f0,4
gdb:m210101f4,4
gdb:m210101f8,4
gdb:m210101fc,4
gdb:m21010200,4
gdb:m21010204,4
gdb:m21010208,4
gdb:m2101020c,4
gdb:m210101e8,4
gdb:g
gdb:m2101023c,4
gdb:m2101023c,4
gdb:m21010240,4
gdb:m21010244,4
gdb:m21010248,4
gdb:m2101024c,4
gdb:m21010250,4
gdb:m21441fa0,4
gdb:m2101025c,4
gdb:m2101025c,4
gdb:X2101025c,4:}] <put breakpoint>
gdb:vCont;c:p10000.-1 <cont all, breakpoint ready>
starting 65537 @210101e8
Hello World
trap callback <stop @ breakpoint>
stopping 65537 @2101025c
gdb:m2101025c,4
gdb:m21010260,4
gdb:m21010264,4
gdb:m21010268,4
gdb:m2101026c,4
gdb:m21010270,4
gdb:m21010274,4
gdb:m21010278,4
gdb:m2101027c,4
gdb:m21010280,4
gdb:m21010284,4
gdb:m21010288,4
gdb:m2101028c,4
gdb:m21010290,4
gdb:m21010294,4
gdb:m21010298,4
gdb:m2101029c,4
gdb:m210102a0,4
gdb:m210102a4,4
gdb:m210102a8,4
gdb:m210102ac,4
gdb:m210102b0,4
gdb:m210102b4,4
gdb:m210102b8,4
gdb:m210102bc,4
gdb:m210102c0,4
gdb:m210102c4,4
gdb:m210102c8,4
gdb:m210102cc,4
gdb:m210102d0,4
gdb:m210102d4,4
gdb:m210102d8,4
gdb:m210102dc,4
gdb:m210102e0,4
gdb:m210102e4,4
gdb:m210102e8,4
gdb:m210102ec,4
gdb:m210102f0,4
gdb:m210102f4,4
gdb:m210102f8,4
gdb:m210102fc,4
gdb:m21010300,4
gdb:m21010304,4
gdb:m21010308,4
gdb:m2101030c,4
gdb:m21010310,4
gdb:m21010314,4
gdb:m21010318,4
gdb:m2101031c,4
gdb:m21010320,4
gdb:m21010324,4
gdb:m21010328,4
gdb:m21010258,4
gdb:g
gdb:X2101025c,4:? <remove breakpoint>
gdb:m2101025c,4
gdb:vCont;s:p10000.10001 <stop thread, trace ready><??c:-1 neden yok>
single step set
starting 65537 @2101025c
trace callback <instruction complete exception>
stopping 65537 @21010260
single step reset
gdb:m21010260,4
gdb:m21010264,4
gdb:m21010268,4
gdb:m2101026c,4
gdb:m21010270,4
gdb:m21010274,4
gdb:m21010278,4
gdb:m2101027c,4
gdb:m21010280,4
gdb:m21010284,4
gdb:m21010288,4
gdb:m2101028c,4
gdb:m21010290,4
gdb:m21010294,4
gdb:m21010298,4
gdb:m2101029c,4
gdb:m210102a0,4
gdb:m210102a4,4
gdb:m210102a8,4
gdb:m210102ac,4
gdb:m210102b0,4
gdb:m210102b4,4
gdb:m210102b8,4
gdb:m210102bc,4
gdb:m210102c0,4
gdb:m210102c4,4
gdb:m210102c8,4
gdb:m210102cc,4
gdb:m210102d0,4
gdb:m210102d4,4
gdb:m210102d8,4
gdb:m210102dc,4
gdb:m210102e0,4
gdb:m210102e4,4
gdb:m210102e8,4
gdb:m210102ec,4
gdb:m210102f0,4
gdb:m210102f4,4
gdb:m210102f8,4
gdb:m210102fc,4
gdb:m21010300,4
gdb:m21010304,4
gdb:m21010308,4
gdb:m2101030c,4
gdb:m21010310,4
gdb:m21010314,4
gdb:m21010318,4
gdb:m2101031c,4
gdb:m21010320,4
gdb:m21010324,4
gdb:m21010328,4
gdb:m2101032c,4
gdb:m2101025c,4
gdb:m21010258,4
gdb:g
gdb:m2101025c,4
gdb:X2101025c,4:}] <HATA put breakpoint>
gdb:vCont;c:p10000.-1 <cont all><HATA -1 gönderdiği için, trace yapmıyor>
starting 65537 @21010260
```

#### ELF file

```
void printHello(void)
{
210101e8:    94 21 ff f0     stwu    r1,-16(r1)
210101ec:    7c 08 02 a6     mflr    r0
210101f0:    90 01 00 14     stw     r0,20(r1)
210101f4:    93 e1 00 0c     stw     r31,12(r1)
210101f8:    7c 3f 0b 78     mr      r31,r1
     cout << "Hello World" << endl;
210101fc:    3d 20 21 04     lis     r9,8452
21010200:    38 69 01 78     addi    r3,r9,376
21010204:    3d 20 21 04     lis     r9,8452
21010208:    38 89 82 48     addi    r4,r9,-32184
2101020c:    48 02 1f a9     bl      210321b4
21010210:    7c 69 1b 78     mr      r9,r3
21010214:    7d 23 4b 78     mr      r3,r9
21010218:    3d 20 21 03     lis     r9,8451
2101021c:    38 89 26 ec     addi    r4,r9,9964
21010220:    48 02 25 45     bl      21032764
}
21010224:    39 7f 00 10     addi    r11,r31,16
21010228:    80 0b 00 04     lwz     r0,4(r11)
2101022c:    7c 08 03 a6     mtlr    r0
21010230:    83 eb ff fc     lwz     r31,-4(r11)
21010234:    7d 61 5b 78     mr      r1,r11
21010238:    4e 80 00 20     blr

2101023c <main>:

int main()
{
2101023c:    94 21 ff e0     stwu    r1,-32(r1)
21010240:    7c 08 02 a6     mflr    r0
21010244:    90 01 00 24     stw     r0,36(r1)
21010248:    93 e1 00 1c     stw     r31,28(r1)
2101024c:    7c 3f 0b 78     mr      r31,r1
    int i = 0;
21010250:    39 20 00 00     li      r9,0
21010254:    91 3f 00 08     stw     r9,8(r31)
    printHello();
21010258:    4b ff ff 91     bl      210101e8 <_Z10printHellov>
        i++;
2101025c:    81 3f 00 08     lwz     r9,8(r31)
21010260:    39 29 00 01     addi    r9,r9,1
21010264:    91 3f 00 08     stw     r9,8(r31)
        i++;
21010268:    81 3f 00 08     lwz     r9,8(r31)
2101026c:    39 29 00 01     addi    r9,r9,1
21010270:    91 3f 00 08     stw     r9,8(r31)
        i++;
21010274:    81 3f 00 08     lwz     r9,8(r31)
21010278:    39 29 00 01     addi    r9,r9,1
2101027c:    91 3f 00 08     stw     r9,8(r31)
```

Comment: The fact that the value of `i` is not used at the end may confuse the compiler, especially with optimisation

Comment: optimization is off and later ```i``` add an ```while(i);``` to make use of it. actually the error happens on an actual project, i++'s are here to simlify the code and testing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. At least *step over* works fine now.

The error was caused by the rs6000_in_function_epilogue_frame_p() function.

As you can see, the function scans forward until the next BLR for 52 (seems familiar) instruction. And it scans backwards until adjustment to stack pointer. These causes it to put a breakpoint to be put on a previous code from the PC and execution cannot be stopped.

The function modified just to return 0.

I don’t have a deep understanding on the host side, and maybe you'll find a better solution.

I suspect there was a design change in previous versions in the step functionality, the Intel architecture code was updated, but PowerPC was forgotten.